# How to make the view full frame even if Sidebar is on in SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

#### Goal

Like the app Maps, views appear to be full frame size when Sidebar is open. Views are under Sidebar.

[image]

#### What I've tried

In order to maximize View's size, I've set the size to be infinity and add view modifier `.ignoresSafeArea()` but it's still not full frame like Maps

You will see the frame of view will be adjusted when I turn on the sidebar

[image]

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            NavigationLink("Test") {
                VStack {
                    Text("Test")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Test")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 400)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
            Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know your question has been answered but I’m curious what the `toggleSidebar` code looks like. I have a use case that your approach could help a lot.

Comment: @Magnas Here it is `NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use transparent content for right side and place map *below* `NavigationView`.

Here is a demo of approach. Tested with Xcode 13 / macOS 12

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        MapView()                // << content here !!
        NavigationView {
            List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                NavigationLink("Test") {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Test")
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Test")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
            Color.clear         // << transparent right !!
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 400)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```