# macOS SwiftUI NavigationView panel disappear once slide completely to left

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI NavigationView issue. When I slide the navigation panel all the way to the left it disappeared. How can I get the left panel back. Also is there a way to allow the panel to be resize (slide) but no disappear. I am trying to figure out how to allow the panel to be able to slide but not completely disappear

```
struct ColorDetail: View {
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        color
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .navigationTitle(color.description.capitalized)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Purple", destination: ColorDetail(color: .purple))
                NavigationLink("Pink", destination: ColorDetail(color: .pink))
                NavigationLink("Orange", destination: ColorDetail(color: .orange))
            }
            .navigationTitle("Colors")
            

            Text("Select a Color") // A placeholder to show before selection.
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: note this from Apple, `NavigationView` will be deprecated, and use these instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: It's a bug. Give a button in toolbar like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608596/how-to-make-the-view-full-frame-even-if-sidebar-is-on-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [workingdog support Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11969817/workingdog-support-ukraine) and [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi), this behavior is indeed a bug, and NavigationView [will be deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) with the release of iOS 16. For your case specifically, it seems like you should consider using `NagivationSplitView`, in particular, this:

```swift
NavigationSplitView {
    /* Sidebar */
} detail: {
    /* Main content */
}
```

When implementing this approach, your result will look something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            /* Sidebar */
            List {
                NavigationLink("Purple", destination: ColorDetail(color: .purple))
                NavigationLink("Pink", destination: ColorDetail(color: .pink))
                NavigationLink("Orange", destination: ColorDetail(color: .orange))
            }
            .navigationTitle("Colors")
        } detail: {
            /* Main content */
            Text("Select a Color") // A placeholder to show before selection.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, the only missing thing for the fully working example is struct ColorDetail{} definition which could be found here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink